# Is there any way to avoid context switching in erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Newbie here coming from Microsoft MVC3+razor.

Say I had:

```
<% if foo %>
   <%= bar %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a way I can have:

```
<% if foo
   magic_function_that_goes_to_output_buffer bar
end %>
```

Does this function exist?

Edit:
To be absolutely clear, I am looking for a solution I can use multiple times within <% %> blocks. Having a solution between <%= %> blocks just moves the problem.

An answer of "No" is acceptable as then I can stop being annoyed by it and just move on.

Solution accepted:
My application_helper looks like

```
    def out(content)
    @output_buffer.safe_concat(content)
end
```

My view looks like

```
    prevReview = nil 
@review.each do |review|
    out render :partial => 'review', 
               :locals => { :review => review, :showDate => (prevReview.nil? ? true : prevReview.updated_at === review.updated_at) } 
    prevReview = review
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way.

But before I tell it, please don't do this unless you have a really good reason. This is because you'll be tied to an implementation detail that may change anytime.

Just post a new question that target your specific problem, you'll certainly get good answers.

Here it is:

```
<% if foo
     @output_buffer.concat("any string will do")
     bar = call_what_you_want
     @output_buffer.concat(bar.to_s)
   end
%>
```

Okay, this works well on Rails 2.x but with Rails 3 you'll concat to a safe output buffer so you should maybe call #safe_concat instead of #concat on the @output_buffer variable.

Comment: Thanks. Functional testing will ensure it never goes bad.

My result was:
(in application_helper.rb)
 def out(content)
  @output_buffer.safe_concat(content)
 end
(in my view)
 prevReview = nil 
 @review.each do |review|
  out render :partial => 'review', 
             :locals => { :review => review, :showDate => (prevReview.nil? ? true : prevReview.updated_at === review.updated_at) } 
  prevReview = review
 end

Comment: I think you may simply render the collection like stated in the rails guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials chap. 3.4.5) ie: (in your view) <%= render :partial => 'review', :collection => @review %> (shouldn't the @review variable get pluralized?). And then in your partial put the logic for showDate: (your partial) <% if @prevReview.try(:updated_at) != review.updated_at; @prevReview = review %> <%= review.updated_at %> <% end %>. I didn't test that, but it should work because the @prevReview variable is kept in the context of the view rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It does, try this:

```
<%= bar if foo %>
```

Edit:

You can do that too:

```
<%= if true 
 "true"
else
 "false"
end %>
```

But if you have much logic involved, you should better use a helper. So in you helper file:

```
def magic_function_that_goes_to_output_buffer(condition)
  if condition
    "true"
  else
    "false"
  end
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= magic_function_that_goes_to_output_buffer(foo) %>
```

Comment: That is very restrictive. What if I have elsif or else sections?

Comment: But I still cant use magic_function in a non-returning block <% %> or multiple times without concatenation.

Comment: def magic_function_that_goes_to_output_buffer(condition)
  if condition1
    "A"
  elseif condition2
    "B"
  else "C"
end

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to look at the haml. With haml code looks cleaner and stylish.

```
  <% if foo %>
       <%= bar %>
    <% end %>
```

This erb code transforms to:

```
 - if foo
   = bar
```

That's all. Couple of useful links [haml site](http://haml-lang.com/) and [haml-rails plugin page](https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails). Good luck!